# Is using memcmp when updating struct in EEPROM okay?

Tags: c, eeprom

I am writing a generic update function for EEPROM which compares old value with new one and then if values differ writes new one to eeprom. This is the function:

```
template <typename T>
void update(uint16_t update_address, T& update_value)
{
    // Do not attempt to read until device is ready
    while (!TM_I2C_IsDeviceConnected(EEPROM_I2Cx_, EEPROM_ADDRESS)) {}
    T current_value;
    read(update_address, current_value);
    if (memcmp(&current_value, &update_value, sizeof(T)) != 0)
    {
        // Do not attempt to write until device is ready
        while (!TM_I2C_IsDeviceConnected(EEPROM_I2Cx_, EEPROM_ADDRESS)) {}
        write(update_address, update_value);
    }
}
```

The problem is comparison. I read that due to padding the variables might differ if they are structures in certain cases and its generally bad idea to use memcmp to compare two structures. But I want my function to be generic. I could assume that "==" operator is defined and use

```
template <typename T>
void update(uint16_t update_address, T& update_value)
{
    // Do not attempt to read until device is ready
    while (!TM_I2C_IsDeviceConnected(EEPROM_I2Cx_, EEPROM_ADDRESS)) {}
    T current_value;
    read(update_address, current_value);
    if (current_value != update_value)
    {
        // Do not attempt to write until device is ready
        while (!TM_I2C_IsDeviceConnected(EEPROM_I2Cx_, EEPROM_ADDRESS)) {}
        write(update_address, update_value);
    }
}
```

but I wonder if in this case a "==" operator is REALLY needed. After all I am really just comparing raw bytes, no logic involved (i.e. uint8_t boolean might be true in both structs even if one is 1 and other 100 and this should be handled properly, but in this case it doesn't matter at all as it should be one and same structure byte-wise), but that padding thing has thrown me off a little. My question therefore is Is it okay in this particular case to use memcmp (T can be any type, probably in a lot of cases a structure) and can padding cause any problems or should I assume or rather explicitly demand "==" operator to be defined prior to using the function?

Comment: Why are you not using a packed struct for storage?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you for mentioning it, in my research I havent encountered it yet. I will surely take a look at it. Interestingly the library I was learning from does byte by byte comparison of type T, but it was written for 8-bit mcu while Im using 32-bit. Maybe that makes a difference in this particular thing.

Comment: Aren't templates considered terrible practice in the embedded C++ world?

Comment: @MattYoung True that they might not be the best choice for embedded systems, I didnt rethink what I was doing enough, I was following in footsteps of EEPROMEx library for arduino which uses templates and thought its okay if it uses them.

Comment: @MattYoung They are *unjustifiedly* considered terrible practice, indeed. But if you know what you're doing, you can only benefit from them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have come to the conclusion that I would have to calculate tradeoff between time wasted by CPU unpacking the structs and time consumed by transferring those waste bytes in structures via I2C in order to decide what is better (CPU has to be able to read ie. 100 structs per second and make some decisions based on the data).

Comment: +1 for a question about how to use modern C++ constructs for an embedded system! @Matt : templates are a very usefull tool for small-system programming. Check my ["Objects? No Thanks!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8sRQMx2qUw)  talk for one apparoach. Check the Kvasir library for a much more radical approach.

Comment: @dim Sounds like you are referring to the old EC++ debate where templates were banned for efficiency reasons. But that's some 15 year old arguments. The main reason template meta programming is still considered terrible practice is not so much related to efficiency nowadays (though that may still be an issue on some compilers). It is considered bad practice because of the needless complexity, increased code bloat and reduced readability, which in turn leads to more bugs and more maintenance problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want your template class to be generic (and it seems you want to), you should be using the == operator. Indeed, there might be uninitialized padding bytes in the struct, and your comparison with memcmp would return false even if the fields all have the same value. Of, course, this requires the == operator to be appropriately defined for the underlying type, but that is a safer assumption than considering all bytes of the struct have significance.

This choice has the following consequences:

- More flexibility: on some underlying types, you may have fields that you don't need/want to compare. It is the case if you have fields that are deduced from other parts of the struct: for example, if the object contains an ID and a name and you know that there is a one-to-one association between name and ID, you just have to compare the ID in the == operator, making the comparison faster. Another example: if, in the struct, there is a hash on the object data, you will first compare the hash to check if objects are unequal to improve speed, before comparing all fields one-by-one.
- The call of the == operator can eventually be inlined by the compiler, whereas the memcmp call certainly won't (unless it is declared inlineable, but I doubt it). This may allow the complier to produce more efficient code. On the other hand, this may also lead to code bloat. Check the reulting compiled code if you have severe constraints on code size. There are [ways](http://gameangst.com/?p=226) to avoid code bloat resulting from templates, but it's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: It is standard practice by compilers to inline functions like `memcmp`. They are often written in assembler too. A custom == operator that compares the same amount of data will not be faster than memcmp, but likely slower.

Comment: @Lundin Inlining of memcmp really depends on your compiler *and* runtime. Inlined memcmp implementations are also sometimes not able to deal with complex SIMD/cache optimizations available on higher-end CPUs, too. So it may actually become [slower than the one provided by libraries](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43052), for some usages. And, most likely, for small objects (a few 32-bit fields), having a naive, inlined code doing manually the compare will be strictly equivalent to the best possible inlined implementation of memcmp the compiler could produce.

Comment: The programmer has to assume that `memcmp` gives the best possible outcome for the given system. Otherwise it is nothing but a compiler bug.

Comment: There are *hundreds* of different implementations of memcmp for a given system, each giving different performance results depending on the way they're used (aligned/unaligned data, length, ...). So, no, you just can't assume the compiler will be smart enough to inline the version that will be the most efficient for your specific usage. You can just assume it will make a code "most probably efficient enough". Anyway, this isn't really relevant. What is relevant is that memcmp, in the specific case the OP described, is **not safe**. He really shouldn't use it.

Comment: You can usually assume that the compiler does a better job than your home-brewn memcmp() though. Very few programmers are experts on what gives best branch prediction and data cache handling for a given MCU. And the only reason why memcmp() isn't safe in the OP's case, is because there are padding bytes in their EEPROM. Which doesn't make any sense to begin with. The alignment requirements of the EEPROM will be completely different to those of the CPU, so the padding bytes are just clutter and waste of space.

Comment: @Lundin: If a programmer knows that the operands to `memcmp` will be 32-bit aligned, and there will be a mismatch within the first four bytes 99% of the time, a library `memcmp` which would be optimal for large blocks that will usually match may be an order of magnitude slower than a rather crude routine which is designed to suit the actual usage pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> I read that due to padding the variables might differ if they are structures in certain cases and its generally bad idea to use memcmp to compare two structures.

Indeed. This is the reason why you shouldn't just blindly dump a struct in eeprom in the first place. Not only do you risk to write garbage padding bytes into the eeprom, but they also take unnecessary space. This is the root of your problem.

There are two possible ways around this:

- Either you ensure that your structs have no padding, if that's feasible for the given system. You can ensure this with a `static_assert` comparing the size of the struct against the size of all members added together.
  To actually remove the padding, you'll have to resort to some compiler-specific command like `#pragma pack`.
- Or you write serialization/de-serialization routines that copy individual members one by one. Slower but much more portable and robust.

The very same problem exists when you wish to send structs over data protocols, so this is nothing unique to the EEPROM case.

Once you have ensured that you actually know the nature of the data stored, you can compare it with `memcmp`. Using a a custom == operator doesn't make much sense, since you want a raw binary comparison anyway - this appears to be an EEPROM driver.

It is a very good idea to compare the data that should be written against the EEPROM before writing it, since this will save write cycles and thereby increase the EEPROM memory's life.

Note that it makes very little sense to write an eeprom driver which works on other types than `uint8_t`. The driver doesn't have to know the nature of the data.

Comment: Yes, I think transferring garbage bytes over I2C is ultimately more time consuming than packing a struct. I will probably serialize members one by one before sending them to eeprom. Problem with comparing data before writing is 128B page size as whole page gets refreshed and that is really annoying with 2 structs per page.
I too have come to the conclusion that those templates are there just for "ease of use" and are actually clutter, all they really do is convert T pointer to uint8_t pointer, multiply sizeof(T) with array length and pass that to function which writes block of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to check whether updating is necessary on this level. EEPROM writing is an extremly time-consuming operation. This check has to be done in the write-function –byte-wise or page-wise–.

A useful set of functions and macros would include knowledge on the internal page organisation of various I²C EEPROMS and allow people to easily create structures which are padded to those page boundaries - instead of page boundaries imposed by the compiler.

Comment: True, the page size is 128B. But problem is reading via I2C takes a lot of time and if I create struct to fit the page (currently my struct is around 100B) I wont be able to sequentially read multiple structs without waste bytes which take time to transfer.

Comment: Ah, you are aware you cannot write across page boundaries with a single I²C command? This only works for reads.

Comment: Yes, but I need speed when reading, not so much when writing as human will input data into device and a few ms doesnt matter. And when device will need to store something (like when power fails you save time of failure) it will be small amounts. However device will then check (read) the list every second I have to make it work under one second.